# How to find the best fit when you have a set of ideal ratios, but some of those are below a minimum?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, set

Say you have a set of ideal ratios, whose sum = 1. For example,

```
set = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3]
```

But suppose that there is a rule stating that none of those should be below a value, if it is not equal to 0:

```
min = 0.25
```

Intuitively we can say a good fit would be:

```
set = [0.25, 0, 0.425, 0.325]
```

But I don't really know what I have done there.

Is there a name for this kind problem? What are general solutions?

Comment: I don't get it, in your example (2nd) you have 2 values above 0.25 :|

Comment: @amit, my mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Now 0 is below 0.25..

Comment: You are fast, I edited that at the same time you posted. Explaining further: or a value is 0.25+, or it should be reduced to 0. This models an ideal investment in certain stocks, but there is a minimum you can invest in a specific stock, so you have to adjust your ideal ratios taking in account the fact you can't invest less than `min` in any of them.

Comment: Does your comment about least squares mean that values below the cutoff could increase to above the cutoff?

Comment: If `min=0.25` and `set=[.24,.76]`, do you want `[.25,.75]` or `[0,1]`?

Answer (score 1):

Let this minimal value be `m`, A general solution could be:

```
while there is a none zero value smaller then `m`:
   x <- lowest value
   for each y != x:
      y += y*x/ (1-x)
   x <- 0
```

It is easy to see that the above loop retains the sum==1 in each iteration because:

sum of all elements excluding x = 1-x

Thus, sum of all increases is

```
 x/(1-x) * [sum of all elements excluding x] = x / (1-x) * (1-x) = x
```

So, in each iteration the total sum was decreased and increased by the same value, so the total sum remained 1.

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Viclib Seems pretty straight forward normalization that works and guatantees all your condition are always kept. Don't recall if I've ever seen it in literature.

Comment: I've tried your algorithm with the set = [0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3], min = 0.25... the result is [0, 0, 0.46875, 0.46875]... http://pastebin.com/Q1spyAQ1 you can try it at LiveScript.net

Comment: Oh, you want it to be the same as your test case? Sorry, misunderstood the question then. Thought there are multiple answers available per input. Will delete soon.

Comment: I wouldn't delete, I think there is just a bug if you have multiple values taking the lowest value.

Comment: Wait, don't. I'm just trying to get why it is not summing up to 1. I don't get why you are adding y*x/(1-x) to y.

Comment: @Viclib It is needed to guarantee that the sum adds up to 1, I proved that the algorithm guarantees the end sum will be 1.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with an ambiguity when 2 values were equal, I would update your answer to reflect that. Anyway, for the case [0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3] the result of that algorithm is [0 0.25 0.375 0.375]. Wouldn't [0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25] be a best fit, as the sum of differences from the ideal is only 0.2, vs 0.5 on your algorithm? Can this be accounted for?

Comment: @Viclib You need to define the metric for a "good solution" better if you consider [0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25] "better" then [0,0.25,0.375,0.375].

Comment: @amit your answered my question perfectly, but you also taught me how to visualize the problem better. The best solution here would be defined as one with the least sum of differences between each element of the input and the output. Do you have a take on this one too?

Comment: I think you need to act on all the elements at the same time.  [.33,.33,.34] with a cutoff of .335 would not result in [0,0,1].

Comment: @Teepeemm true in that case, but [0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3] would regardless of what, because those 0.2 wouldn't hit 0.25 on the second pass and would be thus discarded.

Comment: Looking at it, the `for each y != x:` will act on all elements at the same time.  But you then need to change `y*x/(1-x)` to `y*x/(1-kx)`, where there are `k` elements that tie for lowest.  But I'm going to keep thinking about the least sum of differences.

Answer (score 1):

#### Algorithm

I think this is approximately the algorithm you're suggesting (in Python):

```
def fx(arr, m): 
  arr.sort()
  if arr[0] >= m:
    return arr 

  return _fx(arr, m, 0)

def _fx(arr, m, i): 
  extra = arr[i]
  arr[i] = 0 

  for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
    if arr[j] >= m:
      break
    extra -= m - arr[j]
    arr[j] = m 
    if extra < 0:
      arr[j] += extra
      return _fx(arr, m, i + 1)

  numToBump = len(arr) - j 
  for k in range(j, len(arr)):
    arr[k] += extra / numToBump

  return arr
```

Explanation:

First, we sort the array.  If the first element is above the minimum, we're done.  Otherwise, call the helper method (`_fx`) with our arguments, plus the index to zero out (`0`).

In the helper method, we zero out the `i`th element and store its original value as the "extra" amount we have to distribute.  First we try to bump all elements less than the minimum to the minimum, by taking from `extra`.  If we run out of extra before we finish, we try zeroing the next element.

If we get everything above the minimum, then we divide up the remaining extra between the elements we haven't yet touched.

Note: I'm returning the elements in a different order, but it would be pretty easy to un-sort them at the end.

#### Examples

These all are using a threshold of `0.25`.

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4] -> [0, 0.25, 0.325, 0.425]

[0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4] -> [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Comment: I don't get what it is doing, but could you tell me the results with some inputs? As in, does it take in account that the optimal solution should have the least sum of element-wise differences between input-output?

Comment: @Viclib It does do the least sum thing, although there are an infinite number of solutions that fit that.  I will add a better description of the output and some examples.

Comment: @Viclib Can you suggest some examples you'd like to see?

Answer (score 0):

At least if I understand correctly, you want to take the smallest, and if it's less than the minimum, reduce it to zero. Then give enough of that (if there is enough) to the next smallest to meet the minimum. (If there's not enough, zero that next smallest, add its value to what you're distributing, and repeat).

When you have the smallest up to the minimum, and something left over to distribute among the rest, you want to start by adding up the others to get a sum. Then walk through the others, and divide each number by the sum to get a ratio. Then, the amount that goes to each is the ratio multiplied by the amount you need to distribute.

For example, with your original numbers:

```
set = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3]
```

We zero the second item, and give .05 to the first, leaving .05 to distribute.

We then add the other two to get 0.7. We divide each of the others by that to get their ratios: 0.4/0.7 and 0.3/0.7. Then we multiply 0.05 by each of those ratios to get the amount to distribute to each: 4/7*.05 = .0285714... and 3/7*.05 = .0214857...

So we add that much to each. When we get to the last one, we simply add all that's left, so if there were any rounding errors, our sum remains as it started.